# Trying to center div horizontally AND vertically in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Basically I'm trying to create a similar effect as shown on this url:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/asgdi8i12sgi74x/geniets+byrde.txt

That is; I want to create a div (the box) and center it horizontally and vertically at all times. I'm using Bootstrap 3. It seems like a simply task but I haven't managed to do it.

Would love it you could help me out!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is general to CSS, not bootstrap3. and we normally do it like this:

```
  div {
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       bottom: 0;
       right: 0;
       margin: auto;
  }
```

Comment: Not working https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WExzBL